# Calculating a field from two different tables and show in a DatagridView

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

I need a solution. I want to substract/add a field value from one table with another. I'm giving the details.

I've two tables (same structure).

Table1 - `purchase`   fields : `id, purchase_from, product_name, quantity, rate`

Table2 - `sales`   fields : `id, sale_to, product_name, quantity, rate`

Now I want to substract the quantity from `purchase` table to `sales` table and show the data into a datagridview.

I have tried, but failed. I'm giving you the code snippet.

`Dim PurchasePrdName, SalesPrdName As String
    Dim PurchaseQty, SalesQty As Double`

```
Private Sub LoadPurchase()

    Try
        OpenConnection()
        Dim dcommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim qry As String = "SELECT ProductName,SUM(Quantity) FROM stockitems GROUP BY ProductId"
        dcommand.Connection = conn
        dcommand.CommandText = qry

        Dim dbread As MySqlDataReader = dcommand.ExecuteReader
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        While dbread.Read
            If dbread.HasRows Then
                PurchasePrdName = dbread("ProductName").ToString
                PurchaseQty = dbread("SUM(Quantity)").ToString
            End If
        End While
        dbread.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        CloseConnection()
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub LoadSales()

    Try
        OpenConnection()
        Dim dcommand As New MySqlCommand
        Dim qry As String = "SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM salesitems WHERE ProductName='" & PurchasePrdName & "' GROUP BY ProductId"
        dcommand.Connection = conn
        dcommand.CommandText = qry

        Dim dbread As MySqlDataReader = dcommand.ExecuteReader
        DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
        While dbread.Read
            If dbread.HasRows Then
                SalesQty = dbread("SUM(Quantity)").ToString
            End If
        End While
        dbread.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        CloseConnection()
    End Try

    End Sub
```

and then load this data into DataGridView...

`Private Sub LoadData()
        Try
            LoadPurchase()
            LoadSales()
            Dim PrdName As String = PurchasePrdName
            Dim Qty As Double = PurchaseQty - SalesQty
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add(PrdName, Qty)
            DbGridCustomize()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub`

But it is showing only one product from the table. I'm confusing why!!!

Could you please help me on this ???

I'll be very grateful to you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are only adding one row to the grid and that is the product that is assigned to PurchasePrdName. You either need to bind a collection of values to the grid or you need to iterate through a collection of values. It appears as though all you are doing here is to assign a single value to a variable and then adding one row to the grid with:

```
DataGridView1.Rows.Add(PrdName, Qty)
```

EDIT:

I would change your variable PurchasePrdName and SalePrdName to a collection as you are expecting multiple values to be stored here.

```
Private PurchasePrdName As Dictionary(Of String, Double)
Private SalesPrdName As Dictionary(Of String, Double)
```

Then when you load your purchases and sales you would do something like this instead:

```
While dbread.Read
    If dbread.HasRows Then
        PurchasePrdName.Add(dbread("ProductName").ToString, dbread("SUM(Quantity)"))
    End If
End While
```

Then when you do your sales you need to loop through your products dictionary to pull out each product name. You can store the sales quantity but you could also at the same time calculate the difference and store that. It may well be better to create a class that contains the all of the items instead and store them in one dictionary.

In the load of sales you would iterate your dictionary

```
For Each product In PurchasePrdName.Keys
    Dim qry As String = "SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM salesitems WHERE ProductName='" & product & "' GROUP BY ProductId"

    dcommand.CommandText = qry

    Dim dbread As MySqlDataReader = dcommand.ExecuteReader
    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
    While dbread.Read
        If dbread.HasRows Then
            SalesPrdName.Add(product, PurchasePrdName(product) - Double.Parse(dbread("SUM(Quantity)")))
        End If
    End While

    dbread.Close()

Next
```

Finally you would want to add the rows in a loop too...

```
For Each product In SalesPrdName.Keys
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(product, SalesPrdName(product))
Next
```

You will probably want to change the variable names to reflect their new meanings etc. If you want to store the sales quantity then I would suggest having one dictionary with the product name as the key and a class as the value. The class would consist of the product name, product quantity, sales quantity and the difference between the two.

Comment: Could you please elaborate. I think, I require a loop in the last code i.e. `LoadData()` but I don't know how.

Comment: I have added more detail to the above answer.